# Codeigniter - URI Disallowed characters

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have seen several other questions similar to this but I can't find a solution to my specific problem.

I am getting error `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.` When I send the following request:

```
 http://myrul/login/createNewPassword/reset_token/pwd70xkainz500d57311rli/username/contact%40email.com
```

Now I have identified that the `%` in my `username` is what is triggering the error but I have that allowed in my config file.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

I though this should allow `%` to be allowed in the url. If I set config as

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';
```

Works fine. Is the config string not correct? Or is there another variation of the string I should be using?

Comment: URL decoding seems to happen before disallowed character verification is done, meaning CI is checking for `@`, not `%40`. Simply add `@` to the permitted characters or change the URL to use the email as a GET parameter instead.

Comment: @SolarBear Worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contact%40email.com` is actually **contact@email.com**, but `urlencoded`.

So, the disallowed character you are sending is `@`, not `%`.

If you add "@" to your `permitted_uri_chars` you should be alright.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-@';
```

Comment: Well I'm not sending @ in the url. The whole point of sending it as `%40` is so the `@` is never seen.

Comment: doesn't matter that is not "seen". the webserver sees it. `urldecode`ing happens before url validation. so you **are** sending the "@" char. :)

Comment: Ok, I think what threw me off was my XAMPP local server processes it differently than my live server. So it worked on my local but not live environment. Thanks.