# The URI you submitted has disallowed characters. CI3

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, uri, codeigniter-3

> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

my URL is `http://localhost:8080/project_name/payers/q=member+search`

I have set `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';`

But it still not working

Comment: You should really read the CodeIgniter documentation.  It's written very well and easy to follow.  Quote:  *"Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane."*

Comment: I leave it blank because I want to test it. But it still not working.

Comment: Did you try adding `+` and `=` characters to the default first?  `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-+='; `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter - URI Disallowed characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42072802/codeigniter-uri-disallowed-characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can set what characters are allowed in url/uri in CI Application. 
Please go to application > config > config.php file.

Default allowed chars are

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

You can add more chars to the list to be used in URI for your application

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-=+';
```

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yestE.png) to check the attached screenshot of it.